# Showing every interval of length $c\sqrt p$ contains a quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

The following is known:

> There exists a positive constant $c>0$ such that for every prime $p$ and every subset $A$ of $\Bbb Z_p$ of size $k$, there exists an element $x \in \Bbb Z_p$ such that the set $xA$ intersects every interval in $\Bbb Z_p$ of length at least $\frac{cp}{\sqrt k}$.

I am asked to conclude from this the following:

> There is a constant $d>0$ so that for every prime $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, every interval of length at least $d\sqrt p$ contains a quadratic residue.

I wonder What $A$ to choose, since to apply the known theorem directly I need a set that contains quadratic residues no matter by what we multiply all elements of the set, and no nonzero such set exists. We lookfor a very large subset (of size $p$ up to a constant) by the required length bound.

Comment: Seeing how $\frac{cp}{\sqrt k}$ goes to $d \sqrt p$, my first guess would be to take $k = p$.  Then $A = \mathbb{Z}_p$ and certainly any $x$ is such that $xA$ contains the quadratic residue $x^2$.

Comment: By a slight improved version of the Polya-Vinogradov inequality (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polya-VinogradovInequality.html) there cannot be more than $3\sqrt{p}$ consecutive quadratic residues or more than $3\sqrt{p}$ consecutive non-quadratic residues. Plus: the Legendre symbol is multiplicative.